# Liferay Search over structured webcontent matching attachment's term

Tags: java, elasticsearch, liferay, booleanquery

We have a  webcontent structure “S” with “Document and Media” field.

We have created a webcontent named « W » based on the previous structure « S » with a word file attachment named “a” with “hello” text inside of it.

We know that lucene/ElasticSearch is indexing the content of the attachment if it is a word or pdf file for example.

So we do a lucene search (using booleanQuery, fitering on journalArticle) to retrieves S webcontent to match “hello” search term.

But we saw that lucene, filtering on journalArticle, return a json like object with those data :

"ddm__keyword__87940__attachements_en_US":[
{\"groupId\":\"115863\",\"title\":\"a.word\",\"type\":\"document\",\"uuid\":\"dffd1d3d-8b78-a64c-4d0c-8d004d24cb75\"}]

It only have a reference to the DLFileEntry object.

Is there is a way, with only one request, to retrieve journal article matching word’s attachment?

We saw that Liferay propose “indexer Post Processor” that could help us to store DLFileEntry data inside of a new field of our webcontent but DLFileEntry indexing is asynchronous.

What can we do ?

Comment: Could you explain which API you use and how your request looks like in detail? Because usually you get more than just the attachments. Its important to understand that from the Search-API you get only the things that were stored there during indexing. And from your second to last sentence I would assume that you are looking for a way to retrieve the content of the word attachment _together_ with the journal article content?

Comment: Liferay version :  7.1.1 GA2

We use `IndexSearcherHelperUtil.search(searchContext, searchQuery);` from `com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.IndexSearcherHelperUtil`

We add our structure and journalArticle restriction to the searchContext object, see below :

`searchQuery.addRequiredTerm(Field.ENTRY_CLASS_NAME, JournalArticle.class.getName());
searchQuery.addRequiredTerm(Field.CLASS_TYPE_ID, structureId);`

Comment: For our question, what we want is'not retrieve the attachement and the journal article in one go, but be able to retrieve all journal article maching our search term in the structure or in the attachement content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found a solution :

1. we create a hook indexer post processor for JournalArticle class.
2. in the indexer post processor, we retrieve the dlFileEntry and index
   it through *document.addFile()*.
3. in our portlet we can now request into file content with a
   booleanQuery  (*addterm*) and with *IndexSearcherHelperUtil.search*

only disadvantage is that file content is indexed twice (natively with dlFileEntry and now into journalArticle)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't insist on a single query on ES level I would address it with Hit post processors.

https://dev.liferay.com/de/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/introduction-to-liferay-search#hitsprocessor

I would query for the word in the files and then if there is a hit I would enhance the result with the postprocessor to add/replace the potential web content entry.